# Oracle database query adding table 1 values and display in table 2

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

Tried the query in the mentioned image but could not crack in MySQL database.

This is my table:

[image: This is my table]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Héctor: thank you for the edit. If you see thanks, advance thanks, ASAP begging, urgent begging or please-help-me begging, or any similar fluff, don't bother tidying it - just remove it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a simple aggregation, doesn't it?

```
select sno, sum(amount)
from table1
group by sno;
```